# How to attach tooltip or label for a separator in DailyPilot scheduler?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, daypilot, daypilot-scheduler

Hello I am using **DayPilot scheduler with Angular** and I have multiple **separators** and I want to attach a label or a tooltip on them. So whenever the user hovers on the separator it shows a little info about this separator *(for example: the holiday name)*.

I've searched for it in the [docs](https://doc.daypilot.org/scheduler/separators/) but I couldn't find a way to attach a tooltip on a separator or even create a standalone floating tooltip on a specific date location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out i was using an old version of [DayPilot](https://javascript.daypilot.org/try/); solved when i downloaded and used the latest version.